# Regular Expression to check the spaces and minimum entries in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# for programming!

I want to write one regular expression in c# which will check first and last space in a sentence and will allow spaces in between it as well as there should be minimumm 2 charater entry in field, no limit for maximum characters, no special keys are allowed (@,#,$ etc) characters allowed

Please suggests!

Comment: wat?  You might want to include some positive and negative examples of what you're talking about.

Comment: I do not really understand your requirements. Could you clearify that a bit?

Comment: For example 1) user have to enter minimum 2 characters 2) it should allow characters (Aa-Zz) and (0-9) 3) there will not be any first and last space for that sentence

Comment: If alphanumerics are not allowed, what is allowed? Punctuation and CJK ideographs?

Comment: My fault while writing the question, @,#,$,!....keys are not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear exactly what you want. Your comment -- contradicting the question itself -- suggests something like this, perhaps...

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$
```

This means that the string must start and end with an alphanumeric, and all characters *except* the first and last must be either alphanumeric or whitespace.

Comment: there can be spaces in between the words like 'hello dear' is ok, howeve ' hello dear ' is not valid